# Make Content visible when UITableView is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using this method to enlarge the height of my cell when it is selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) {
      return 100.0;
  }

  return 44.0;
}
```

I want to display a `UIImageView` in the area that is only visible when the cell is enlarged and I want it to be hidden when the cel is deselected.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Your code seems ok to make the cell bigger when it's selected. Just add the image to the bottom part of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it should only be visible when the cell is expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct for enlarging the cell.

*You can also do the same by following below mentioned steps as well -*

1) Add a property to keep track of the selected cell

```
@property (nonatomic) int currentSelectedRow;
```

2) Initialize it with a value

```
self.currentSelectedRow = -1;
```

3) Return cell height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     if([indexPath row] == self.currentSelectedRow) {
          return 100.0;
 }

     return 44.0;
}
```

4) Set the selected row in cell selection method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
        // code to do on cell selection

        // set the row number of current selected cell
        self.currentSelectedRow = indexPath.row;

        // animate the selected row
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

5) Set the selected row to invalid row number(-1) in cell deselection method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{       

        // invalid row number
        self.currentSelectedRow = -1;

        // animate the selected row
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

**Note**: It is just a sample code, you can customize it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example

```
NSInteger selectedIndex;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UITableView *tbl=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 75, 320, 300)];
    [tbl setDelegate:self];
    [tbl setDataSource:self];
    [self.view addSubview:tbl];

    selectedIndex=-1;
 }


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 8;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]init];

   UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 70, 40)];
   [lbl setText:@"cell"];
   [cell addSubview:lbl ];

    UIImageView *imgVw=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 6, 50, 30)];
   [imgVw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
   [imgVw setTag:400+indexPath.row];
   [imgVw setAlpha:0.0];
   [cell addSubview:imgVw];

   return cell;

}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   [tableView beginUpdates];

   UIImageView *imgVwCellBg=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:400+indexPath.row];

   if (selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
   {
      selectedIndex=-1;
      [imgVwCellBg setAlpha:0.0];
   }
   else
   {
      selectedIndex=indexPath.row;
      [imgVwCellBg setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
      [imgVwCellBg setAlpha:1.0];
   }

   [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   UIImageView *imgVwCellBg=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:400+indexPath.row];

   selectedIndex=-1;

   [imgVwCellBg setAlpha:0.0];

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   if(selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
   {
      return 100;
   }
   else
   {
      return 44;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this once

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 4;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 0)];
    [imageView setTag:1000];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image_2"]];
    [cell addSubview:imageView];

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView beginUpdates];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];

    if (selectedIndex==indexPath.row)
    {
        selectedIndex=-1;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 0)];
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 170)];
        }];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 0)];
}];

    [tableView endUpdates];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row)
    {
        return 200;
    }
    else
    {
        return 75;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is `selectedIndex` a NSDictionary, NSArray or NSIndexPath?

Comment: It is NSInteger.    NSInteger selectedIndex;

Answer (score 1):

I think problem maybe `isEuqal:` method for NSIndexPath, not like NSString, you can't just user `isEuqal:` to judge NSIndexPath is equal.

```
  if([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) {
```

replace with

```
NSIndexPath *selectedPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
if(selectedPath.row == indexPath.row && selectedPath.section == indexPath.section){
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so Here is what i have done, using all you have given me and doing it

```
 @property (nonatomic) int currentSelectedRow;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.currentSelectedRow = -1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString * cellId = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *contentView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:304];
contentView.hidden = YES;



return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
self.currentSelectedRow = indexPath.row;



[tableView beginUpdates];
UIImageView *contentView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:304];
contentView.hidden = NO;

if (_currentSelectedRow == indexPath.row)
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

        [contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 0)];
    }];
}
else
{
    _currentSelectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        contentView.hidden = NO;
        [contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 200, 170)];
    }];
}

[tableView endUpdates];



}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *contentView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:304];
contentView.hidden = YES;

// invalid row number
self.currentSelectedRow = -1;

// animate the selected row
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView endUpdates];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if([indexPath row] == self.currentSelectedRow) {
    return 100.0;
}

return 44.0;
}
```

Thanks to all your input
Be sure to vote up the question it will help many